# Picking unique records in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I have a table with multiple records of peoples name, I draw out a prize winner every month. What is a query in SQL that I can use so that I pick up a unique record every month and the person does not get picked on the next month. I do not want to delete the record of that person.

Comment: Create a separate table where you store each winner name and date.

Comment: Add a column may be previous winner and update it on picking ,then select the records where previouswinner column has null value or any of your choice

Comment: To write a query first you must think on how do you want to structure your data. Think about it and edit your question adding your table or tables structure so others could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a **new column** as a **flag** named anything like 'prizeFlag' make it boolean take only 0 and 1 or anything as you like, make it's default value is 0 means not get a prize yet
when you select a random column update this filed with 1 means take a prize
 
when you select a random column next month, Add a condition in **WHERE** Clause say the prizeFlag not equal 1 to avoid duplication

Answer (score 0):

One should store whether a person has already won. A *date* would make sense to allow people after say 10 years to win again.

```
ALTER TABLE ADD won DATE;
```

A portable way would be to use a random number function outside the SQL.

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id), COUNT(*) FROM persons
```

With a random number one can get the next valid ID.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM persons WHERE won NOT IS NULL AND ID >= ?
int randomno = minId + new Random().nextInt(maxId - minId);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, randomno)

UPDATE persons SET won = CURRENT_DATE WHERE ID = ?
```